Jupyter notebook error in loading nbextensions
I have recently in stalled nbextensions after downgrading my notebook to 6.5.7, after opening the nbextensions tab, I am being faced with message - Snap! Failed to load config section "common"
Snap!** Failed to load config section "tree"
Snap!** Failed to load config section "edit"
Snap!** Failed to load config section "notebook"
Am I doing something wrong with it since I had tried resolving this issue with other posted questions on this website, but they did not seem to get the issue solved
On also running the command to find failed jason files -
import glob
import os
import json
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_path
for d in jupyter_config_path():
for p in glob.glob(os.path.join(d, 'nbconfig', '*.json')):
try:
with open(p, 'r') as f:
json.load(f)
print('File {0} is OK.'.format(p))
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
print('Failed JSON file is:', p)
output -
File C:\Users\Yogendar.jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json is OK.
File C:\Users\Yogendar.jupyter\nbconfig\tree.json is OK.
Similar, there were results for only these 2 files.
Since I had checked C:\Users<Name>.jupyter\nbconfig, I only saw notebook.json and tree.json and in the error there is edit and common too. I wish to resolve this issue, and I need someone's assistance.
